# Reload table Ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I am developing a table , the table reload with ajax/jquery but table doesn't empty , append the next content to table.

```
<table class="table" id="pujas">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {                  
                $.ajax({
                url:'../ajaxpujas',
                 dataType:'json',
                type:'get',
                cache:true,
                success:json,

               });

               function json(data){
                   $(data).each(function(index,value)  {
                        console.log(value);
                        var table = '<tr><td>' + value.id + '</td><td>' + value.id_user + '</td><td>' + value.importe + '</td></tr>';
                        $('#pujas').append( table );
                        });
                        }
                }, 1000);
            });
</script>
```

Any idea about this ? How could I do the refresh table correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Add tbody id

```
 <tbody id='tbodyid'>
```

And clear before append

```
$("#tbodyid").empty();
```

In your code

```
  function json(data){
                   $("#tbodyid").empty();
                   $(data).each(function(index,value)  {
                   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to clean your `<table>` contents before you reload it with new content.

However, you should add and manage your table contents from within your `<tbody>` element in this case to preserve your `<thead>` above.

So, in your json function you can do someting like:

```
$('#tbody_id').html (""); // This cleans the previous content.
```

And then add your new content as you were doing it:

```
$('#tbody_id').append ('Your html content');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using append but not appending an element. 
You can add the HTML from the var table by using the '.html()' and adding the HTML to your current HTML.

A different approach is to actually create elements and then use the .append